# Как проверить, выбрана ли дата в MonthCalender?

Tags: c#, winforms

На форме есть, предположим, `TextBox` и `MonthCalender`, а также кнопка.
Кнопка становится активной когда что-то записано в `TextBox`
и в `MonthCalender` выбрана дата. Потом эта дата записывается в БД,
но возникла проблема: Пользователь может выбрать число, а потом нажать на месяцы и элемент так и останется, а в БД почему-то добавится совсем другая дата.

Как можно проверить, что выбрано число? Если юзер перейдёт на месяцы, то кнопка станет недоступной.

Comment: Чем плох DateTimePicker?

Comment: Уже сделал через него и такой проблемы нет )

Но всё же, есть ли такая возможность для MonthCalender ?

Comment: Не совсем понятна проблема, если число уже было выбрано то какая разница что сейчас смотрит юзер месяцы или года .

Comment: К примеру было выбрано 7 ноября, потом мы перешли на месяцы.
Нажимаем ОК, а дата будет не 7 ноября, так как он на каждой неделе стартует с разной даты.

Comment: Есть же MonthCalendar.DateChanged Event и без разницы чем там юзер занимается.

Comment: _"может выбрать число, а потом нажать"_ -- после выбора числа, контрол можно заблокировать. Control.Enabled = false; Также можно подключить обработчик к событию DateChanged и т.д.

Comment: Всем спасибо  за ответы!